# Orientation locked when background is transparent

Tags: android

I want my activity has a transparent background, so I created this theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And applied it to the Manifest File:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
```

It's working fine. When this "android:windowIsTranslucent" is set true, the activity got transparent as it should, but the screen orientation doesn't change, it only stays at portrait orientation. Is there a way to apply a transparent background that works with portrait and landscape orientation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should work if you set `android:screenOrientation="sensor"` on the Activity in question.

Comment: Thank you, it works! But should I add it on all my activities?

Comment: You only need it on transparent activities.  The reason is that by default, Android will take the screenOrientation parameter from the activity underneath any transparent ones.  Since the launcher (for example) normally forces portrait orientation, you need to override that explicitly.